# Process data from googledrive with a local environment

Tags: local-storage, google-colaboratory, google-drive-shared-drive

I am tryng to process some data that I have in google drive, my scrip run well when i am in a hosted execution environment but it is too slow. So I tried to use a local execution environmente but i cannot acess to google  drive because the code to do that requires a module named 'termios' and it is only avaible on Linux

[image]

Does anybody knows how can I process the data in my google drive using a local environment?

I tried to install termios with conda and pip but there are no files for that module.

Answer (score 0):

Since you run google colab in the local environment, you will be unable to access your data from google drive. You have two options now:

1. Download your data to your PC and import it.
2. Download Google Drive software and sync. it to your local machine, where everything in your drive will be available locally. Then you can import your data.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, i think i will try to process the data online.